# How to delimit row data to be added dynamically to a jtable when there are empty values in it?

Tags: java, swing, jtable

My requirement is to dynamically add rows and columns in a `JTable`.

I tried a simple code but I am stuck in a place where I don't know how to delimit when there empty values in row data. I tried to split the row data using "\s+" delimiter but this doesn't work when there are empty values in row data. My code works only when there are values for the row data.

Please find below my code

---

```
String[] resultLines = data.split("\n", 0);

parsedResult = new String[resultLines.length][];
String cols[] = resultLines[1].split("\\s+");
String[] columnsParsed = new String[cols.length];
for (int i = 0; i < cols.length; i++) {
    String colName = cols[i];
    columnsParsed[i] = colName;
}
parsedResult[0] = columnsParsed;

int k = 1;
for (int j = 3; j < parsedResult.length; j++) {
    parsedResult[k] = resultLines[j].trim().split("\\s+");
    k++;
}

String[] columns = parsedResult[0];
String[][] data1 = new String[parsedResult.length - 1][];
for (int i = 1; i < parsedResult.length; i++) {
    data1[i - 1] = parsedResult[i];
}

DefaultTableModel model = new DefaultTableModel(data1, columns);
jTable1.setModel(model);
```

**Please find below the data for reference**

```
Handles   NPM(K)    PM(K)      WS(K)     CPU(s)   Id  SI  ProcessName                                                  
-------   ------    -----      -----     ------   --  -- -----------                                                  
    322      17     3308      13800              2572   0  armsvc                                                       
    171      10     6304      11224       0.11   3836   0  audiodg                                                      
    591      31    11864      42480       1.39   3660   9  backgroundTaskHost                                           
   1488      55    28736      61776              1892   0  CcmExec                                                      
     42       4     2332       3816       0.05  10720   9  cmd                                                          
     74       6     5704       4452       0.09  12032   9  cmd                                                          
     58       5     4312       6028       0.25  12188   9  cmd                                                          
     42       4     2324       3800       0.06  13760   9  cmd                                                          
    235      14     3004      10092              1896   0  CmRcService                                                  
    216      12     2520      13128             12980   0  CompatTelRunner                                              
     88       5      916       4060             14084   0  CompatTelRunner
```

Can you guys help me with this issue?

Comment: What's the original format of the data?

Comment: As I understand, you want to build a table model using some data you have. Please post some sample input data. That will make it easier to understand your requirement.

Comment: @MadProgrammer, I have updated my question with sample input data. Please have a look. Thanks

Comment: @PrasadKarunagoda, I have updated with sample input data

Comment: My guess is you should be delimitating against a tab character rather then a white space character

Comment: Are you suggesting to delimit with tab? @MadProgrammer

Comment: @ashwini That what I said - but I'm "guessing" as it's impossible to know without the original data

Comment: Tab won't work @MadProgrammer, I tried that.

Comment: @ashwini Then, the only choice you have is to determine the min number of spaces between columns and manually split the string - or get the data in a better format

Comment: Overlapping is occuring when i split with space. Is there any other delimiter to split or how to pass empty values to cells for which we are getting empty value in row data

Comment: First option is not possible @MadProgrammer. Second one is I get data from a server so i cant change the format. Is there any other better solution than this?

Comment: @ashwini Nothing that isn't going to require you to write a large amount of `String` handling code

Comment: @MadProgrammer the whole data we get from the server is completely a single string. We have to split based on new line character("\n") which gives row data. Then we are splitting the rows for columns with space("\\s+") delimiter.

Comment: you might be able to split the rows with `\\s{2,7}` as your minimum is 2 and your max is 7. if that doesn't work you could replace any match of 7 spaces to a comma, then remaining gaps of spaces to a comma, then if something has 3 commas make it 2 (repeated a couple times). then split on commas. or something along those lines. I hope that makes sense.

Comment: If the server is giving you a STRING and is windows based, it is likely using an old command. but the output looks very much like `get-process` i would re-do the way it outputs the file, if you use `get-process | convertto-csv` or `get-process | export-csv filename.csv` you would have an appropriate comma separated file

Comment: i just did this in powershell, meaning bash or Java should be able to do something similar`$temp = get-process | foreach {"$($_.Handles)  $($_.NPM)    $($_.PM) $($_.WS)     $($_.CPU) $($_.Id)  $($_.SI) $($_.ProcessName)"}; $temp -replace "\s{7}","," -replace "\s{1,10}",","` and it split out a "csv" version of the output, but it's overkill, like before converting to CSV is much easier. BUT bash or Java could do it. My code is UGLY it's just to make a concept of the output you get, and then convert it to commas between fields. it's not perfect, but some tweaking to the replace style works

Comment: @RobertCotterman the output we get from the server is of get-process only

Comment: can you not set it to `get-process | convertto-csv` if the data is overload, you can select the properties inbetween with `get-process | select handles,npm,pm,ws,cpu,id,si,processname | convertto-csv` mind you, the default is manipulated to reduce size, NMP(K) is "kilobytes" not the full value reported.

Comment: We can do @RobertCotterman but the problem is I tried this command in my local system command prompt, I got so many columns in the output. But when i executed get-process command alone, I got 8 columns

Comment: that's because the default output is the microsoft chosen lines, if you want an exact duplicate, IN CSV form, i'd be happy to create the line of code you need.

Comment: In the lower version of powershell(3.0), this command "get-process | convertto-csv" is not working

Comment: @RobertCotterman Can you please write common code which will be suitable for all the powershell versions?. It will be very helpful for me. Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of the "delimiter" approach, if you make use of the fact that your data is right-aligned (except the last column), you can try the approach I have demonstrated below.

Since the alignment of data is exact, I am taking an exact number of characters for each column. Try this and see whether it works for you.

(I have started from `resultLines` in your code.)

```
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JScrollPane;
import javax.swing.JTable;
import javax.swing.table.DefaultTableModel;

public class ParseTableData {

  public static String[] parseRow(String line) {
    String[] row = new String[8];
    row[0] = line.substring(0, 7).trim();
    row[1] = line.substring(7, 15).trim();
    row[2] = line.substring(15, 24).trim();
    row[3] = line.substring(24, 35).trim();
    row[4] = line.substring(35, 46).trim();
    row[5] = line.substring(46, 53).trim();
    row[6] = line.substring(53, 57).trim();
    row[7] = line.substring(57).trim();
    return row;
  }

  public static void main(String[] args)
  {
    String[] resultLines = new String[] {
        "Handles   NPM(K)    PM(K)      WS(K)     CPU(s)   Id  SI  ProcessName                                                  ",
        "-------   ------    -----      -----     ------   --  -- -----------                                                  ",
        "    322      17     3308      13800              2572   0  armsvc                                                       ",
        "    171      10     6304      11224       0.11   3836   0  audiodg                                                      ",
        "    591      31    11864      42480       1.39   3660   9  backgroundTaskHost                                           ",
        "   1488      55    28736      61776              1892   0  CcmExec                                                      ",
        "     42       4     2332       3816       0.05  10720   9  cmd                                                          "
    };

    String[] columns = resultLines[0].split("\\s+");

    String[][] data = new String[resultLines.length - 2][];
    for (int i = 2; i < resultLines.length; i++) {
      data[i-2] = parseRow(resultLines[i]);
    }

    DefaultTableModel tableModel = new DefaultTableModel(data, columns);

    JFrame frame = new JFrame();
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    frame.getContentPane().add(new JScrollPane(new JTable(tableModel)));
    frame.pack();
    frame.setVisible(true);
  }
}
```

**VERSION 2**

Try this version of my program. Here, the number of columns and column widths are calculated dynamically.

(There might be possible enhancements to the algorithm used in `calculateColumnWidths()`. I just want to demonstrate the approach.)

```
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JScrollPane;
import javax.swing.JTable;
import javax.swing.table.DefaultTableModel;

public class ParseTableData {

  public static int findFirstRowWithNoEmptyCells(String[] resultLines) {
    String[] columnNames = resultLines[0].split("\\s+");
    for (int i = 2; i < resultLines.length; i++) {
      String[] row = resultLines[i].trim().split("\\s+");

      if (columnNames.length == row.length) {
        return i;
      }
    }
    throw new IllegalStateException("Not a single complete row.");
  }

  public static int[] calculateColumnWidths(String rowWithNoEmptyCells) {
    int columnCount = rowWithNoEmptyCells.trim().split("\\s+").length;
    int[] columnWidths = new int[columnCount];

    int currentColumnIndex = 0;
    int currentWidth = 0;
    boolean nonSpaceCharFound = false;
    for (int i = 0; i < rowWithNoEmptyCells.length(); i++) {
      char c = rowWithNoEmptyCells.charAt(i);
      if (c == ' ') {
        if (!nonSpaceCharFound) {
          currentWidth++;
        }
        else {
          columnWidths[currentColumnIndex] = i;
          currentWidth = 1;
          nonSpaceCharFound = false;
          currentColumnIndex++;
        }
      }
      else {
        nonSpaceCharFound = true;
        currentWidth++;
      }
    }
    return columnWidths;
  }

  public static String[] parseRow(String line, int[] columnWidths) {
    String[] row = new String[columnWidths.length];
    for (int i = 0; i < row.length; i++) {
      if (i == 0) {
        row[i] = line.substring(0, columnWidths[i]).trim();
      }
      else if (i == row.length - 1) {
        row[i] = line.substring(columnWidths[i-1]).trim();
      }
      else {
        row[i] = line.substring(columnWidths[i-1], columnWidths[i]).trim();
      }
    }

    return row;
  }

  public static void main(String[] args)
  {
    String[] resultLines = new String[] {
        "Handles   NPM(K)    PM(K)      WS(K)     CPU(s)   Id  SI  ProcessName                                                  ",
        "-------   ------    -----      -----     ------   --  -- -----------                                                  ",
        "    322      17     3308      13800              2572   0  armsvc                                                       ",
        "    171      10     6304      11224       0.11   3836   0  audiodg                                                      ",
        "    591      31    11864      42480       1.39   3660   9  backgroundTaskHost                                           ",
        "   1488      55    28736      61776              1892   0  CcmExec                                                      ",
        "     42       4     2332       3816       0.05  10720   9  cmd                                                          "
    };

    int indexOfFirstRowWithNoEmptyCells = findFirstRowWithNoEmptyCells(resultLines);
    int[] columnWidths = calculateColumnWidths(resultLines[indexOfFirstRowWithNoEmptyCells]);

    String[] columns = resultLines[0].split("\\s+");

    String[][] data = new String[resultLines.length - 2][];
    for (int i = 2; i < resultLines.length; i++) {
      data[i-2] = parseRow(resultLines[i], columnWidths);
    }

    DefaultTableModel tableModel = new DefaultTableModel(data, columns);

    JFrame frame = new JFrame();
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    frame.getContentPane().add(new JScrollPane(new JTable(tableModel)));
    frame.pack();
    frame.setVisible(true);
  }
}
```

Comment: Hi @Prasad Karunagoda your code is working but my requirement is to dynamically add rows since our number of columns are not fixed size, it varies. Thats why I tried to split with delimiter "\\s+" but it fails when we get empty values in rows. So Do you have any idea/approach on how to fix this issue?

Comment: @ashwini, my approach can handle dynamic rows and columns also. It only relies on the fact that width of a particular column is constant (a constant number of characters). If you can explain the dynamic nature of your data, I might be able demonstrate how my approach can handle that.

Comment: how can we dynamically add rows and columns with your approach? I don't understand. And my dynamic nature of data is column size varies each time and there can be empty values in the row data i get.

Comment: If we can solve this issue with your approach can you please explain that.

Comment: @ashwini, to parse any data, there should be some kind of a pattern. If there is no pattern at all, then parsing is impossible. The pattern I see in your data is, in a given input, width of a particular column is the same (hence the nice alignment). So, as the first step of your program, calculate these column widths. Then use those widths to parse the data.

Comment: your approach will work only if there are 8 columns. If the number of columns is 9 or 10, how can we do? Note: The number of columns is not pre-defined in our case, only during the runtime we will get to know the number of columns.

Comment: @ashwini, see "Version 2" of my program. It calculates the number of columns and column widths dynamically.

Comment: Okay thanks @Prasad. I will try this and let you know

Comment: I tried with the code you provided, its working perfectly. Thank you so much

Comment: @ashwini, you are welcome. Thanks for accepting the answer :)

Answer (score 1):

Working with you, I do NOT have a Java answer; however, since you are using PowerShell to perform the request, here is a line of code that works on all powershell versions.

It will spit out a CSV format of just the data you're already getting, instead of a String with spaces.

`get-process | select handles,@{n='NPM(K)';e={[math]::round($_.npm/1kb)}},@{n='PM(K)';e={[math]::round($_.pm/1kb)}},@{n='WS(K)';e={[math]::round($_.ws/1kb)}},@{n='CPU(s)';e={[math]::round($_.cpu)}},id,si,processname | convertto-csv -notypeinformation`

This is one line.  All I did was take their output, and selected the default values, and performed the necessary math to get the same results.  Then I converted it to a CSV format.

if you don't want the final output to have "quotes" in it, this should do the trick

`get-process | select handles,@{n='NPM(K)';e={[math]::round($_.npm/1kb)}},@{n='PM(K)';e={[math]::round($_.pm/1kb)}},@{n='WS(K)';e={[math]::round($_.ws/1kb)}},@{n='CPU(s)';e={[math]::round($_.cpu)}},id,si,processname | convertto-csv -NoTypeInformation | % {$_ -replace '"',''}`

**Let me know if the 0's are annoying, I can remove those. otherwise it's defaulting null to 0**

to just get the raw output, you can do this...

`get-process | select handles,npm,pm,ws,cpu,id,si,processname | convertto-csv -notypeinformation`

DUE TO PowerShell not having convertto-csv, this should work...

`get-process | select @{n='Handles,';e={"$($_.handles),"}},@{n='NPM (K),';e={"$([math]::round($_.npm/1kb)),"}},@{n='PM(K),';e={"$([math]::round($_.pm/1kb)),"}},@{n='WS(K),';e={"$([math]::round($_.ws/1kb)),"}},@{n='CPU(s),';e={"$([math]::round($_.cpu)),"}},@{n='Id,';e={"$($_.id),"}},@{n='SI,';e={"$($_.si),"}},@{n='ProcessName';e={"$($_.processname)"}} | ft`

Another solution is to save it to a csv, and then just cat that file...

`get-process | select handles,@{n='NPM(K)';e={[math]::round($_.npm/1kb)}},@{n='PM(K)';e={[math]::round($_.pm/1kb)}},@{n='WS(K)';e={[math]::round($_.ws/1kb)}},@{n='CPU(s)';e={[math]::round($_.cpu)}},id,si,processname | export-csv -Path c:\temp\temp.csv -notypeinformation; get-content c:\temp\temp.csv`

Comment: @RoberCotterman thanks for the command, but this is not working for lower versions of powershell. I am getting this error message "'convertto-csv' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file."

Comment: i just added a line of code to the answer. Does that work for you?  It's only flaw is it includes the dashes "----" between the headers and values  I also gave the headers commas. If you have `export-csv` which was standard on ps v1... you can output it to a file, THEN cat the file back to yourself. just have a temp file you overwrite each time, and change "convertto-csv" to "export-csv" and add a filename

Comment: Hi @RobertCotterman, i tried this command "get-process | select handles,npm,pm,ws,cpu,id,si,processname" in the server, even this is not working. I got error message like "No file name could be found for your query". But when I tried this same command in my local system command prompt, I got output. I am really confused, dont know how to proceed further. can you help me with this

Comment: If you could paste the whole error, I might be able to help. I would also possibly ask your question in the Powershell forum.